# SQL always returns all rows on SELECT query performed on a large table

Tags: php, mysql

When performing the following query on a small test database (100 records), MySQL (phpMyAdmin) returns the number of rows as expected:

```
SELECT ReportedDate 
FROM table
WHERE ReportedDate IN (
       SELECT ReportedDate  
       FROM table
       GROUP BY ReportedDate  
       HAVING count(*) > 1 
       ORDER BY ugid, ReportedDate
 )
```

However when I perform the same query on the actual table (1.5 million records), MySQL returns all rows as if it would with a `SELECT * FROM table` query.

Thank you for any kind of help

Comment: Both tables the same?

Comment: Yes, both tables are the same.

Comment: For same table why you are going for sub query?

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery isn't needed, and with a large data set will impact performance.

Instead of using the subquery and `count(*)`, you might try this:

```
SELECT ReportedDate  
FROM table
GROUP BY ReportedDate  
HAVING count(DISTINCT ReportedDate) > 1 
ORDER BY ugid, ReportedDate
```

Notice the distinct in the having clause.

Comment: you can't order by `ugid` there. I think it's not even needed.

Comment: No way to know without the table schema. You can order by a column in the table, even if it isn't in the list of columns returned.

Comment: No. Not when you are aggregating only on `ReportedDate`. You can however use an aggregate function on it. Something like - `order by max(ugid), ReportedDate`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your table does not have unique `ReportedDate` values - they appear in table at least twice each.